# How to use list index in Soql

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

```
list<string> lst=new list<string>();
lst.add('name');
system.debug('lst[]'+lst[0]);
 system.debug([select count() from account where lst[0]!='' limit 1]);
```

I am getting below error

> Line: 4, Column: 51 unexpected token: '['

How to use List Index in soql.Please suggest

Comment: It seems like lst[0]!='' is a tautology, and that lst[0] is not a field.  If you are trying to compare to the Account.Name field, try using dynamic soql to build your query.  If not, does 
    list<string> lst=new list<string>();
    lst.add('name');
    system.debug('lst[]'+lst[0]);
    system.debug([select count() from account where Name!=:lst[0] limit 1]);

Comment: If any of the below answers [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) if you want to use a variable as field selector in your query:

```
AggregateResult aggResult = Database.query('select count(Id) countResult from account where ' + lst[0] + ' != null limit 1');
System.debug(aggResult.get('countResult'));
```

Or even simpler:

```
Integer recordCount = Database.countQuery(Database.query('select count() from account where ' + lst[0] + ' != null');
```

Comment: Count() does not exist in SOQL as far as I know !!!

Comment: I updated my answer. This should work.

Comment: @benahm You're completely wrong about that.

Comment: @AdrianLarson nice solution !

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah think that Count(*) does not exist,  am I right ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use SOQL in this fashion, you'll need to write a [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) query such as below. Additionally, you'll need to use [Database.countQuery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)

```
list<string> lst=new list<string>(); lst.add('name');
system.debug('lst[]'+lst[0]);

String queryStr = '';

queryStr += 'select count() from account where '; queryStr += lst[0] + ' != \'\' limit 1';
system.debug(database.countQuery(queryStr));
```

Comment: Thanks for response.But my aim is to get count of all field values populated in records.Like in my list {Name,LastName,No_Of_Users__C} fields then it needs to  be display count for all three fields

Comment: list<string> lst=new list<string>();
lst.add('name');
lst.add('Total_Contacts__c');

for(integer i=0;i<=lst.size();i++){
    String queryStr = '';
queryStr += 'select count() from account where '; queryStr += lst[i] + ' != \'\' ';
system.debug(database.countQuery(queryStr));
}

Comment: I have prepared above code .

Comment: But getting below error{Line: 8, Column: 1
System.QueryException: value of filter criterion for field 'Total_Contacts__c' must be of type double and should not be enclosed in quotes}

Comment: Yeah stick with `!= null`. Safe across all field types.